# R change dplyr distance of Y axes

Tags: r, dplyr

`` gs %>% group_by(country) %>%  ggplot(aes(x=country,y=`gdp_per_capita ($)`)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip() ``

How can I change the Y-axes so I can see the countries better [image]

Comment: Make your plot taller? I'm not sure exactly what you want. There's only so much text that can fit in such a small space.

Comment: There's too many countries for one static graph (without a scroller option). You could try `facet_wrap` function if you want to group the graphs by continent

Comment: it would help if you use `dput` to post the aggregated data, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: You can make the font smaller (e.g., `... + theme_gray(base_size = 9)`), or you can make your plot bigger. Or you can change your plot.

Comment: You could use `... + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8))` to set the y axis font to a smaller size

Answer (score 0):

You can set the character of xlabel more smaller,and set the height of the figure more bigger

Comment: To make this answer as helpful as possible to future readers, could you post the actual code that would accomplish this?